# Check java version during program load

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to check which java version my software is running under.

I'd like to verify during load time my software is running on at least

Comment: System.getProperty("java.version")

Comment: Can you finish your last sentence.

Comment: How many duplicate answers do we need?

Answer (score 5):

To get the java version you can use any of these depending on the version you want:

```
java.specification.version
java.version    
java.vm.version 
java.runtime.version
```

However, note that java versions are not equivalent between operative systems. So Java 6 on OSX does not mean the same thing as Java 6 on Windows. So, I would recommend you to also get the OS where the application is running, if you wish to determine if a given feature is available:

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

As a general guideline, all of this stuff is in the System package. A trick I use is iterate through all the available fields to have an idea of what I can use:

```
import java.util.Map;

class ShowProperties {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> e : System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use java.version property to retrieve the jre version.

```
 String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");

if ((!javaVersion.startsWith("1.6")) && (!javaVersion.startsWith("1.7")) && (!javaVersion.startsWith("1.8")) && (!javaVersion.startsWith("1.9")))
{
  // error
}
```

Comment: You've got extra parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`System.getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

```
1.7.0_21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version")
```